# Rails 4 Ubuntu ignoring concerns folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been developing a Rails 4 app on Windows.  I recently switched to Ubuntu (13.10) and brought my project over.  I'm suddenly encountering a new error.

I have several controllers that use the same authentication logic, so I moved that code to a concern called "Authenticating.rb" and put it in my app/controllers/concerns folder.  I then put

```
    include Authenticating
```

at the beginning of each controller.  This worked perfectly under Windows, but in my new Ubuntu version it throws this error:

```
    Routing Error
    uninitialized constant UsersController::Authenticating
```

When I comment out the include line it works just fine.  Additionally it works if I explicitly require the concern file (require "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/concerns/Authenticating.rb").  However I don't want to have to do this for every controller, and I shouldn't have to--Rails is supposed to load this automatically.
Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

EDIT:  I should add that on Windows I was using ruby 1.9.3 and on Ubuntu I've moved to 2.0.0.  Might this have something to do with it?

Comment: what does `Authenticating.rb` looks like ?. BTW it should be `authenticating.rb`

Comment: Hey thank you!  Just changing the name to the lowercase authenticating did the trick!  I still don't know why it worked on Windows and not Ubuntu (nor do I know why I used an uppercase filename...), but who cares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename `Authenticating.rb` to `authenticating.rb`